# Диалог в стиле MFC на WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gui, mfc

Windows 7. Создаю диалог по шаблону с помощью DialogBoxIndirect. Шаблон - массив байт, выдран из exe-шника использующего MFC. Диалог отрисовывается один в один, как в упомянутом exe-шнике, только:
1. кнопки квадратные,
2. рамка вокруг окна жирная (как в калькуляторе или блокноте)
3. titlebar более широкий.

[image: Справа exe-шник использующий MFC, слева приложение использующее WinAPI.]

Первую проблему победил с помощью прагмы:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Как лечатся оставшиеся 2 проблемы?

Набросал с нуля исходник (платформа x64, UNICODE):

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<CommCtrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#define PASSWORD_ID_LEN 16
#define MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH 256
#define DIID_ED_MACHINE_ID 0x3e8
#define DIID_ED_PASSWORD 0x3ea
#define DIID_ED_PASSWORD_ID 0x3e9
#define DIID_BT_CREATE_ID 0x3eb

void CreateId(HWND hDlg)
{
  BYTE PasswordID[PASSWORD_ID_LEN];
  char text[MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH];
  GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, DIID_ED_PASSWORD, text, MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
  int i = (int)strlen(text);
  if (i)
  {
    _itoa_s(i, (char *)PasswordID, PASSWORD_ID_LEN, 10);
    SetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, DIID_ED_PASSWORD_ID, (LPCSTR)PasswordID);
  }
  else
    SetDlgItemText(hDlg, DIID_ED_PASSWORD_ID, L"");
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (message)
  {
  case WM_INITDIALOG:
  {
    RECT rc;

    GetWindowRect(hDlg, &rc);

    int xPos = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - rc.right) >> 1;
    int yPos = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - rc.bottom) >> 1;

    SetWindowPos(hDlg, 0, xPos, yPos, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);

    SetDlgItemText(hDlg, DIID_ED_MACHINE_ID, L"machine id");

    return TRUE;
  }
  case WM_COMMAND:
  {
    int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case DIID_ED_PASSWORD:
    {
      if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
        CreateId(hDlg);
      break;
    }
    case IDOK:
    case IDCANCEL:
    {
      EndDialog(hDlg, wmId);
      return TRUE;
    }
    case DIID_BT_CREATE_ID:
      CreateId(hDlg);
      break;
    } // switch (wmId)
    break;
  } // case WM_COMMAND
  } // switch (message)
  return FALSE;
} // LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND , UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM )

int APIENTRY wWinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icce;
  icce.dwSize = 8;
  icce.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
  assert(InitCommonControlsEx(&icce));

  // 0x3e8 - Edit с Id.
  // 0x3ea - Edit с паролем.
  // 0x3e9 - Edit с Id пароля.
  // 0x3eb - Button "Создать ID"
  // Этот дамп содержит шаблон диалогового окна. Получен из Иды, при исследовании оригинального MFC приложения.
  const wchar_t caption[] = L"WinApiLikeMfc - тест";
  const BYTE dlg_template1[] = {
    0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x90,
    0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x76, 0x01, 0xa1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
  };
  const BYTE dlg_template2[] = {
    0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4d, 0x00,
    0x53, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x53, 0x00, 0x68, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00,
    0x44, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x67, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x50, 0x07, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x68, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x00, 0x12, 0x04, 0x32, 0x04, 0x35, 0x04, 0x34, 0x04, 0x38, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04,
    0x35, 0x04, 0x20, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x04, 0x30, 0x04, 0x40, 0x04, 0x3e, 0x04, 0x3b, 0x04, 0x4c, 0x04,
    0x3a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x80, 0x00, 0x81, 0x50, 0x11, 0x00, 0x37, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x00, 0xea, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x50, 0x3d, 0x01, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0xeb, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x80, 0x00, 0x21, 0x04, 0x3e, 0x04, 0x37, 0x04, 0x34, 0x04, 0x30, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04,
    0x4c, 0x04, 0x20, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x50, 0x3d, 0x01, 0x8c, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x80, 0x00, 0x12, 0x04, 0x4b, 0x04, 0x45, 0x04, 0x3e, 0x04,
    0x34, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x50, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x68, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x3a, 0x04, 0x3e, 0x04, 0x3c, 0x04,
    0x3f, 0x04, 0x4c, 0x04, 0x4e, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04, 0x35, 0x04, 0x40, 0x04, 0x30, 0x04, 0x3a, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x08, 0x80, 0x50,
    0x11, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x00, 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x81, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x50,
    0x07, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00, 0x68, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x00,
    0x49, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x04, 0x30, 0x04, 0x40, 0x04, 0x3e, 0x04, 0x3b, 0x04,
    0x4f, 0x04, 0x3a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x80, 0x08, 0x80, 0x50, 0x11, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x00, 0xe9, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x07, 0x00, 0x81, 0x00, 0x68, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

  BYTE *pdlg_template = new BYTE[sizeof(dlg_template1) + sizeof(caption) + sizeof(dlg_template2)];
  BYTE *p = pdlg_template;
  memcpy(p, dlg_template1, sizeof(dlg_template1));
  p += sizeof(dlg_template1);
  memcpy(p, caption, sizeof(caption));
  p += sizeof(caption);
  memcpy(p, dlg_template2, sizeof(dlg_template2));

  LRESULT res = DialogBoxIndirect(
    hInstance,
    (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)pdlg_template,
    nullptr,
    DlgProc
  );
  delete[] pdlg_template;

  return res == -1 ? 1 : 0;
} // int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE , _In_opt_ HINSTANCE , _In_ LPWSTR , _In_ int )
```

Вывод:

```
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "D:\Work\test\WinApiLikeMfc\x64\Debug\WinApiLikeMfc.exe". Символы загружены.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\comctl32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"WinApiLikeMfc.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
```

Comment: Используя Spy++ вы можете посмотреть стиль оригинального окна и выставить у своего такие же свойства.

Comment: Проверял, стили окна совпадают. Да и как они могут не совпадать, если используется DialogBoxIndirect с тем же шаблоном? В стиле класса в MFC приложении присутствует дополнительный стиль CS_GLOBALCLASS, но он не должен влиять на отображение...

Comment: Манифест тоже совпадает с тем, что работает в приложении MFC?

Comment: Вы вызвали в своем приложении [InitCommonControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775695(v=vs.85).aspx)/[InitCommonControlsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Манифест совпадает. InitCommonControls/InitCommonControlsEx пробовал - от них вообще нет эффекта.

Comment: А саму библиотеку подгрузили (comctl32.lib)? Аналогичный вопрос на enSO: [How to enable common controls in a Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977583/how-to-enable-common-controls-in-a-windows-app)

Comment: Да, библиотека автоматически подгружается, если присутствует прагма для генерации манифеста, проверял с помощью ProcessExplorer. Если прагму закомментировать, библиотека не подгружается.

Comment: И манифест работает, без него кнопки квадратные.

Comment: Проблема в пунктах 2 и 3.

Comment: А какая библиотека подгружается-то? В output посмотрите лог. Ну и конечно хотелось бы увидеть минимальный код, который воспроизводит Вашу проблему.

Comment: comctl32.dll подгружается. comctl32.lib подключал, когда использовал InitCommonControls(). Завтра выложу код.

Comment: Посмотрите в output, какая версия библиотеки подгружается.

Comment: "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\comctl32.dll". Добавил исходник и вывод.

Comment: У меня win7, но Ваш диалог отличается от тех, что приложены к вопросу: [активный](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhp5s5nbiyqzw4z/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-19%2022.57.28.png?dl=0) и [неактивный](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4b000dqmyiqdppl/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-19%2022.59.29.png?dl=0). Версия `comctl32.dll` таже: `6.0.7601.18837`

Comment: Отличия минимальны. В любом случае, присутствует та же жирная рамка вокруг окна, которой нет у mfc приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался! Все дело в поле IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.MajorSubsystemVersion PE заголовка. Если туда записать значение 5, рамка станет тонкой, что логично.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта выбрал Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2010 (v100), получил окно без рамки =)
До этого было: Visual Studio 2017 (v141).

Comment: Правда не совсем понятно, почему так...

Comment: В vs2013 это не помогает

Comment: А вот в vs2015 помог Platform Toolset, равный `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`

Comment: Набор подгружаемых библиотек идентичен. Манифесты - тоже. Выкладываю оба варианта, может кому-то захочется покопаться в PE (там минимальные различия): [v140](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4di3gv23essq4i9/v140.exe?dl=0) и [v140_xp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3hcshftr77qaer/v140_xp.exe?dl=0)

Comment: Во, спасибо за наводку и участие! Как я раньше не догадался обратить внимание на поле  IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.MajorSubsystemVersion ...